# Jboss HDScanner taking up 100% with eclipse debugger = SLOW

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss5.x

I'm not sure how I got to this state, but last time I had to re-install eclipse to fix it, and today it happened again.

Running jboss 5.1.0GA, eclipse helios (last time galileo), jdk 1.6.0_17.

Basically, after a hot-deploy, running jboss in debug mode is incredibly slow.  JVM/Computer/Eclipse restarts do not fix it.  Running jboss in a command window and connecting eclipse as a remote debugger shows the same problem.  If I look the the jmx-console thread cpu usage, the HDScanner thread is taking up 100% cpu time.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer that worked for me: http://community.jboss.org/message/195037

Disable your breakpoints, one of them might cause the problem

Comment: unfortunately, I no longer am working on that configuration so I can't verify it, but it seems reasonable.